# React setState odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React, in the following code I am passing data between two components via the parent. Flow is from `Search` to the parent `App` then to another child `Sidebar`. I am able to send to both from Search to App and App to Sidebar individually but for some reason `setState` is not behaving as expected making the link to trigger a refresh of `<Search updateMenu={this.handleSearchResult} />` as you can see in the `console.log` code comments below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Search from './Search';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

class App extends Component {

   constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
         menu: []
      }
   }

  handleSearchResult = (array) => {

    // always the correct value
    console.log('in ', array);

    this.setState( {menu: menuList})

    // 1st call : empty
    // 2nd call : previous value not showing on 1st call + new value as expected 
    //            does not trigger  <Sidebar list={this.state.menu}/>
    console.log('out', this.state.menu);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        // not refreshing
        <Search updateMenu={this.handleSearchResult} />

        <Sidebar list={this.state.menu}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging `this.setState()`. Is not so straight forward. `this.setState()` is asynchronus.

Here is a [reference](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b) on Medium.

Comment: great link! found the solution there. The issue was with `setState` indeed and the workaround is not assigning `props` to the children `state` and render the children with the `prop` directly instead of `state`